# Sequence of bash commands fails when enclosed in if ... fi - Why? And how to write it in POSIX style?

Tags: bash, if-statement, posix, background-process

The following sequence of commands works fine

```
EHRbase_VERSION=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec)
echo ${EHRbase_VERSION}
java -jar application/target/application-${EHRbase_VERSION}.jar --cache.enabled=false > log &
grep -m 1 "Started EhrBase in" <(tail -f log)
```

But when I try to run them conditionally they don't work as I want

```
if [ "${MY_ENV}" != "FOO" ]; then
  EHRbase_VERSION=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec)
  echo ${EHRbase_VERSION}
  java -jar application/target/application-${EHRbase_VERSION}.jar --cache.enabled=false > log &
  grep -m 1 "Started EhrBase in" <(tail -f log)
fi
```

The result is

```
0.13.0
[1] 17584

# from here it seems to hang and I have to exit w/ CTRL+C
```

What is going wrong?
How to write it correctly in BASH?
How to write it in POSIX?

Comment: For POSIX compatibility, you can simply replace the process substitution with a pipe: `tail -f log | grep -m 1 "Started EhrBase in"`.

Comment: BTW, note that we ask that each question be about exactly one problem. While "how to write it in POSIX?" was easily answered (by replacing the process substitution with a pipeline, as chepner mentions), permitting questions to incorporate multiple other questions makes housekeeping (particularly, maintaining exactly one canonical question for each problem programmers tend to encounter) harder, and hence is against the rules / grounds for being closed as "too broad".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: If `file` is a regular file (and not a named pipe), `tail -f file` never finishes. If there *isn't* any message that matches `Started EhrBase in` in your file, then, it's normal and expected for this code to hang forever.

It'll never finish even without the surrounding `if` either -- the surrounding code is surely a red herring.

---

Maybe you want to just wait for up to a certain amount of time to see the log message? `timeout` (from GNU coreutils) is your friend:

```
java -jar "application/target/application-${EHRbase_VERSION}.jar" \
    --cache.enabled=false >log & app_pid=$!
if ! tail -f log | timeout 30s grep -m 1 "Started EhrBase in"; then
  echo "WARNING: Did not see a startup message even after waiting 30s" >&2
  if kill -0 "$app_pid"; then
    echo "...although EHRbase is still running" >&2
  else
    echo "...and EHRbase did not successfully start" >&2
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for pointig out the most obvious thing: "It'll never finish even without the surrounding if either" . I was blind for a moment :) For successfull startup of the application a db must be running - which I haven't checked (shame on me!). Your answer helps me to avoid running into this issue again.